# Swift on MacOS - how can i save response from PHP post function to Global Varible

Tags: swift, macos, post

i am attempting to query a web service that reports back if a value exists or not in a database. I can print the response in console but i am unable to save it to a variable i can use elsewhere in my code.
if the value exists the response will be in JSON if not the value will be null.
i have another function that checks if the user is approved or not then either continues or disconnects them.
help :/

```
func ApprovedQuery(Quser: String){
    let Url = String(format: LogUserCheck)
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }

    let postString = "user=" + Quser

    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        //if let response = response {
            //print(response)
        //}               
                do {
                    guard let info = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
                        //print("User Not Approved")
                        return
                    }
                    //print("User Approved")
                    return
                } catch {
                print(error)
            } 
} .resume()
```

}

i've tried using a struct and variables but it always prints blank with i print the variable in another function.
i've also tried returning a string (the response) from the original function to another that saves the value but still is blank...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible use case for a singleton. You could create a session manager class and tack values onto it that you need to keep around. It would look something like this:

```
class YourSingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = YourSingleton()
    private init() {}

    var isApproved: Bool = false
}
```

Here's how you'd update it:

```
YourSingleton.sharedInstance.isApproved = true
```

You can read more about the singleton pattern [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton). Some folks have strong opinions on this pattern. Personally, I don't care for it, but without knowing more about the architecture of your app and what you're trying to do, I can't present alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrian, The app is checking if the user is Approved and either doing 1 of 2 things. once i do the user check i have a function that runs when the app starts the will do things based on the returned value of this response from the web service. for instance, if i implement what you have described i would like to do this with the result: 

    `If YourSingleton.sharedInstance.yourGlobalVar = 0 { 
Print('user is NOT Approved') 
} else if YourSingleton.sharedInstance.yourGlobalVar = 1 { 
Print('User is Approved')`

Comment: I just updated the var to be a Bool with an initial value of `false`. You could create a protocol for what to do when that happens and if you've got a class that conforms to the protocol, you can adopt that protocol and write an implementation for it. You could also use `Combine` or `RxSwift` to observe changes, which is the most modern way to do that. You may want to take a peek at those further down the line.

Comment: @CurtisHealy What happened with this?

Comment: Hey mate, I'm still not able to use response in another function. i can print the response to console but when i assign the responseString to a Variable or even return it our of the function it just displays blank.

Comment: You could assign whatever your response is to a var in the singleton and you should be able to access it elsewhere in your app without persisting it to disk. You could also set the `isApproved` var to fire a notification to do stuff, too. Then anything that's an observer of the notification would be able to act on it. Anyway, keep me posted if you get it working.

Comment: so on my viewWillAppear func i have the following: 
`ReadUsernameFromFile()   
ApprovedQuery(Quser: username)   
StartupFunctions()   
}`  
now the startup functions i want to have the ApprovedQuery finished so i can do a check what value it is depends on which way the app goes.
basically was it happening is within the ApprovedQuery i am printing the response to see where it comes out and it prints after the startup functions have completed.  
how can i get this to wait until a response comes back before continuing?

Comment: I've implemented DispatchGroup and i seem to have got it working to how i want. once its complete 100% i'll post it up